# Should I throw a 404 to a request like /photo.php?id=123 if photo #123 does not exist?

Tags: html, http, http-status-code-404

The script will be called from a URL like `example.com/photo.php?id=123` or `example.com/photos/123` depending on if the have the pretty URLs featured enabled.

If photo #123 does not exist, a request to `example.com/photos/123` should throw a 404 error. But, what about `example.com/photo.php?id=123`?

Comment: Is a 404 your only failure handling option?  Is there no way to handle the non-existent image gracefully, such as redirect to `example.com/photo.php`?

Comment: Of course the right thing to do is to make it a graceful 404...  Something like http://stackoverflow.com/foo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The relevant RFC is 2616, specifically the sections on [status codes](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html), [requests](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec5.html), and [URIs](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.2).  Specifically, the query string is considered **part** of the URI, so a `404` is the proper response since it means:

> The server has not found anything
>   matching the Request-URI.

If you can know that a photo has been permanently deleted, you may return `410`.

I would not return `200` and say "no results found."

Answer (score 3):

You should treat both `...?id=123` and `.../123` URLs the same, cause they are equal - they just have a little bit different form.

And yes, you should throw an *404 - **Not Found*** error cause given resource doesn't exists. However 404 pages shouldn't never look like:

> 404 Not found - you're @#$@#$@!

*404* for URL like `...photo.php` should contain a list of suggested resources (different photos that user might wanted to visit), some kind of search form - in other words: it should be a page that allows me to do something rather that just throw error message.

Answer (score 1):

That depends, I suppose.

If `photo.php?id=123` is a page showing the photo with an id of 123, then yes, it should throw a 404. 404 means that a resource was not find when it was expected to be found - this is semantically correct.

However, on the odd chance that your semantic intent for `photo.php?id=123` was for it to be a page *searching* for a photo with the id of 123, then it's perfectly correct to return 200 with a message saying that no results were returned.

Ultimately, it doesn't make a huge amount of difference. I'm not very well acquainted with how HTTP response codes affect the way search engines index your page, but I suspect that 404's will not get indexed in the same way. You probably don't want the page being indexed if there's nothing to display.

TL;DR I would throw 404.

Comment: "Ultimately, it doesn't make a huge amount of difference." It does for search engines. I'm not an expert and I don't know to which extend, but if you always return a 200 with the same content, you have multiple pages pointing to the same content. I think this is bad..

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should throw a 404 if it has never existed:

> The server has not found anything matching the Request-URI. No indication is given of whether the condition is temporary or permanent.

But if it has existed before, you should respond a 410:

> The requested resource is no longer available at the server and no forwarding address is know

From [Status Code Definitions](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)

Comment: That link confirms that 404 does in fact apply to the entire URI, including query string.

I was scared that a 404 on photo.php?id=123 would scare browsers from loading photo.php?id=334, but it seems that is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should throw the 404. This you can easily make using a .htaccess file,

Hope that helps,